# Certain hash in URL combaining with on-page click-event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to locate if there is a certain hash, eg. `#nameofthehash`, in the URL and then do stuff with my code. But it doesn't only need to check if the URL contains `#nameofthehash`, it also needs to check if one of the on-page buttons is clicked. If that's done it needs to run the code.

The code works without the second line. I just don't know how to implement the second line correctly.

```
$('a[href="#groeien"]').click(function(),
$(location.hash).contains("#groeien") {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent('.label').addClass("active");
    $('#groeien').slideDown(1000);
    $('#ontdekken').slideUp(1000);
    $('#ondernemen').slideUp(1000);
    $('#spelen').slideUp(1000);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Update: I have created a jsfiddle to show the current situation, http://jsfiddle.net/qeDam/3/

Comment: how `function(),$(..){` works??? it should be `function(){...}` ????

Comment: Hello C-link, I know this doesn't work, therefore I am asking you guys how to implement this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$('a[href="#groeien"]').click(function () {
    if(window.location.hash.indexOf("#groeien") > -1) {
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent('.label').addClass("active");
        $('#groeien').slideDown(1000);
        $('#ontdekken').slideUp(1000);
        $('#ondernemen').slideUp(1000);
        $('#spelen').slideUp(1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Felix! Unfortunately this doesn't work and I think because `if(window.location.hash.indexOf("#groeien") > -1)` is now part of the click function, but I guess it has to be `$('a[href="#groeien"]').click(function ()` or `if(window.location.hash.indexOf("#groeien") > -1)` and then do the stuff. Is it possible to combine these two?

Comment: Could you take a look at the code please once again? I have also updated the question with a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/qeDam/3/